# И ещё во что-то(,) помимо учебы

Tags: пунктуация

"Нужно вложить свою энергию и ещё во что-то(,) помимо учебы".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дополнения с предлогами  кроме, вместо, помимо, сверх, за исключением, наряду с и др. обособляются в зависимости от смысловой нагрузки, степени распространения оборота, близости к основной части предложения и т. д. В данном случае вы можете обособить, а можете нет, на Ваше усмотрение. Это  зависит от того, хотите ли Вы особенно выделить слова "помимо учебы" .Обособление дополнений в большинстве случаев  остается на усмотрение автора.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что в данном случае запятую лучше не ставить. Розенталь пишет, что подобные сочетания могут обособляться "в зависимости от смысловой нагрузки, степени распространения оборота, близости к основной части предложения и т. п."  В качестве доказательств факультативности обособления таких случаев он приводит примеры: "*Как бы человек ни стремился **помимо школы**, сам по себе получить знания, он всё-таки будет, как говорят, самоучкой. - Многие из бойцов, **помимо своей винтовки**, были вооружены трофеёными автоматами.*"

Answer (score 0):

Я бы запятую не поставила. Степень распространения оборота здесь не достаточно высока.

Comment: Все на усмотрение автора. Сделайте паузу, повышение голоса и на слове  ВО ЧТО-ТО и на словах ПОМИМО УЧЕБЫ - запятая нужна. Не делайте паузу, понижение голоса к концу предложения - запятая нужна. Это и называется  - "в зависимости от смысловой нагрузки"

Answer (score 0):

Инна права: "Степень распространения оборота здесь не достаточно высока". Здесь "помимо" явно относится конкретно к местоимению "что-то" (ср.: *"Нужно вкладывать свою энергию и ещё во что-то **другое**"*.